# DATE RANGE NOT BETWEEN two dates from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, between

I have two tables related to each other [t1] & [t2] with two columns: [id]
 & [date].  I am hoping to retrieve the [id] and [date] from [t1] where no [t2].[date] falls on or one year prior to the MIN([t1].[date]) .

Basically excluding [id]s that have a [t2].[date] (any date occurrence - dynamic) 'on or one year prior to the earliest [t1].[date]' .  Any [t2].[id]s before one year from MIN([t1].[date]) are ok, and any [t2].[id]s after MIN([t1].[date]) are good as well.  If any [t2].[date] value fall in the one year range, that [id] should be excluded from the returned data.

Conceptually I want something like:

```
SELECT [id]
FROM [t1]
WHERE [t2].[date] NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, [t1].[date]) AND [t1].[date]
```

But I'm struggling with how to approach this; use a JOIN/UNION, DECLARE variables, a WHERE clause.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

```
/* Adding this new information below: */
```

I like the response by Scott; however, I don't think I made my 'conceptual code' coherent enough originally.  I think I'm looking for something more like this, but I am returning an error (An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.):

```
SELECT [id]
FROM [t1]
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT * FROM [t2] WHERE [t2].[date]
    BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, MIN([t1].[date])) AND MIN([t1].[date]))

 /* Adding this new information below: */
```

I believe I have found the solution to original inquiry.  Please give an 'Arrow Up' if you like it!

```
SELECT DISTINCT [t1].[id]
FROM [t1]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [t2]
                  WHERE [t2].[id] = [t1].[id]
                  AND [t2].[date] BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -365, [t1].[date])
                                          AND [t1].[date])
```

Comment: I will just leave this here...https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for NOT EXISTS!

```
SELECT [id]
FROM [t1]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [t2] 
                  WHERE [t2].[date] BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, [t1].[date]) AND [t1].[date])
```

Update to compare to Min(T1.Date):

I'm not as familiar with Sqlserver - oracle has Analytic functions which make this much mor straightforward.  You can probably accomplish this just using  a subquery like so:

```
SELECT [id]
FROM (SELECT [id], min([date] AS minDate from [t1] GROUP BY [id]) AS t1_min
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [t2] 
                  WHERE [t2].[date] BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, [t1_min].[minDate]) AND [t1_min].[minDate])
```

Comment: I like this, but can apply this to a MIN Date range from t1

Answer (score 1):

WHERE date < StartDate OR date > EndDate